# Add/customise font stacks in Marketing Cloud

Tags: email, marketing-cloud

Within Marketing Cloud's email studio, is there a way to add additional font stacks and/or customise the existing font stacks that are applied when you set the font for a block of text or a tag/class?

Comment: if you mean in the UI - the answer is No, but yes.  No, you cannot change the default UI options, BUT you can create a custom Content Block via the Content Block SDK that can have these options. BUT this is heavy development work required in order to build it.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to use custom fonts in your emails. Here is a great article that details the ways you can achieve this and the pitfalls to watch out for: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/guides/web-fonts-in-email/

[This part of the article](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/guides/web-fonts-in-email/#five) shows how to import and reference custom fonts.

Make sure you do font compatibility checks for difference devices and browsers.

Comment: Thanks for this (useful info!), but I was really referring to the ability to create your own font stack rather than using web fonts.